# Web Push Notification (using service worker)

Tags: javascript, .net-core, service-worker, web-push, service-worker-events

Am following this project to add web push notifications using service-worker
[Push Notifications and ASP.NET Core](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/12/push-notifications-and-aspnet-core-part.html) and the complete project [Demo.AspNetCore.PushNotifications](https://github.com/tpeczek/Demo.AspNetCore.PushNotifications). Everything works fine, my only problem here is that when I send 2 or more notifications only for the last notification received, On click fires (self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {...) in the service-worker. the rest they don't do nothing.
how to make it work even for older notification (I think this happens only with chrome) ??

any help would be greatly appreciated

**this is my service-worker.js :**

```
const pushNotificationTitle = 'Demo.AspNetCore.PushNotifications';

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {        
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(pushNotificationTitle, {
        body: event.data.text(),
        icon: '/images/push-notification-icon.png'
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    );
});
```

---

I send two or more notifications and put breakpoint in (self.addEventListener('notificationclick').
notificationclick event is only called when i click on the last notification received !!!!!!!!